# O these bot checks

Tags: feature-request, fun, captcha

I am forever being asked if I am a bot, simply because I am so active, especially with the edit button. Can someone write a program that I can click on and it will do it for me?

Comment: And I even got checked when I asked this question.

Comment: Well, after you gain enough reputation (10k I think) the captcha rates are lowered.

Comment: Lowered!!! Why not stopped?!!! I sometimes get five captchas for every question I ask.

Comment: @Arlen Er. In a row? Or you're editing five times?

Comment: Dang, there's already a project called Skynet on GitHub.

Comment: How do we know that you are not actually a bot? In fact, it would be quite clever of you to post this - throwing us off your trail. But I'm on to you...

Comment: The lowered rate at 10k (yes, @jjn, it's 10k) is *extremely lowered*. I actually haven't run into one at all since breaking 10k, even during periods of high activity. Besides, wouldn't a program to solve a captcha be... kinda letting the robots win?

Comment: @Mickeal, edited 5 times.

Comment: @Grace... the robots have won, we just don't know it yet.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We need Captchas to prevent bad behavior. Someone could easily write a program that would create lots of bad edits or ask lots of bad questions. Stack Overflow could be overrun with spam.

Even though you have some rep, having Captchas in place minimises the amount of damage you can do with your account and also minimises the amount of damage others can do with your account. It's a safety net.

Also, the whole point of a Captcha is that humans are able to solve them and programs can not. If someone could write a program to accomplish this, the Captcha would be outdated and a new one would have to be implemented.

Comment: Perhaps a question where you had to spot irony would prevent bots pretending to people?

Comment: It still stands to reason that once you have reached a certain rep level, you have something to lose, and are unlikely to use an evil program to flood SO with crap.

Comment: @Pekka: True, but you still need to stop those who would do so in other people's names. Lots of hacking goes on via 'bots.

Comment: @RobH I don't see a problem here: Accumulating thousands of reputation points is a lot of work, and the account would get burned and shut down when you run the bot once. Too much effort for what ultimately be zero effect, because all bot-generated contributions from that account  would be easy to delete

Comment: @Pekka, if you have a high repping account and it was hacked, someone could write a bot to do really destructive things. It might be a while before it was caught.